# Has elementary OS team considered creating elementary OS to be a rolling Distribution?

Tags: system-installation, updates

Has elementary OS team considered creating elementary OS to be a rolling Distribution?

Just a thought as I think it's better than reinstalling elementary OS when Loki is updated to a new version.

Comment: taking a look at the [elementary OS design philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#Design_philosophy), stability seems very important, and a rolling release might go against that. - also: the question is offtopic